# дублирование картинки на сервере с изменением размера

Tags: php

На сервере в папке folder1 есть картинка, у нее разрешение 1200 на 600 пикселей.

Мне нужно средствами php сделать копию этой картинки, уменьшить ее до 300 на 200 пикселей, и переместить в папку folder2 - то есть, чтобы получилось две копии одной и той же картинки на сервере, но разных размеров и в разных папках.

вот так я примерно собираюсь сделать

```
$filename = './'.$fold.'/' . mt_rand(100,999) . date('YmdHis') . mt_rand(100,999) . '.' . $match[1]; //создаем уникальное имя
```

основная задача - это как добраться до этого файла. Допустим, он у нас в переменной $image
  исправил немного для наглядности вот такой функцией я делаю все

```
  function imageResize(array $src, $fold, $width, $height, $crop=0) {
//обозначиваем папку и копируем исходное

if( empty($src['tmp_name']) || !empty($src['error']) || !preg_match('~\.(jpe?g|png|gif)$~i', $src['name'], $match) ) {

    $retimg = "error0";
    return $retimg; //если нет файла возвращяем ошибку нуль

} else {

    $filename = './'.$fold.'/' . mt_rand(100,999) . date('YmdHis') . mt_rand(100,999) . '.' . $match[1]; //создаем уникальное имя

    if (FALSE == move_uploaded_file($src['tmp_name'], $filename)) { 
        $retimg = "error1"; 
        return $retimg;} // двигаем картинку если ошибка выдаем ошибку один

//начинаем ресайз!

    if(!($info = getimagesize($filename))){ //проверка размеров

        if(file_exists($filename)) { @unlink($filename); }

        $retimg = "error2";
        return $retimg; //если нет размера возвращяем ошибку дуа
    }   
    $w = $info[0];
    $h = $info[1];

    //еще меньше ? прерываем ресайз !
    if($w < $width && $h < $height) {

    $retimg = $filename;
    return $retimg;

    } else {
    //если ресайз нужен то продолжаем!
    $type = $match[1] == 'jpg' ? 'jpeg' : $match[1];

    $create = 'imagecreatefrom' . $type;
    $img = $create($filename);
    //вычисляем

        if($crop){
        $ratio = max($width/$w, $height/$h);
        $h = $height / $ratio;
        $x = ($w - $width / $ratio) / 2;
        $w = $width / $ratio;
        } else {
        $ratio = min($width/$w, $height/$h);
        $width = $w * $ratio;
        $height = $h * $ratio;
        $x = 0;
        }

        $new = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);

        // прозрачность для гиф и пинг
        if($type == 'gif' || $type == 'png') {
        imagecolortransparent( $new, imagecolorallocatealpha($new, 0, 0, 0, 127) );
        imagealphablending( $new, false );
        imagesavealpha( $new, true );
        }
        //сохраняем чьл получилось
            imagecopyresampled( $new, $img, 0, 0, $x, 0, $width, $height, $w, $h );

            $save = 'image' . $type;
            $save = $save($new, $filename);
            $retimg = $filename;
            return $retimg;
    }
}
```

}

как думаете для моих целей подойдет?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Странно все это, конечно, но...

```
$size=getimagesize($filename); // тут берем параметры нужной картинки
// определяем сжатие, если нам нужно соблюсти пропорции, установив рамки картинки, т.е. размеры могут картинки не смогут быть больше указанных
$x=$size[0]/300; 
$y=$size[1]/200;
$w=300;
$h=$w*$size[1]/$size[0];
if ($x<$y) {
    $h=200;
    $w=$h*$size[0]/$size[1];
}
// либо ставим жесткие размеры, если нужно уменьшить картинку и обрезать лишнее
/*
$w = 300;
$h = 200;
*/
ResizeImage($filename, $w, $h);

function ResizeImage($filename, $w, $h) {
    $ratio = $w/$h;
    $dest_img = imagecreatetruecolor($w, $h);
    imagefill($dest_img, 0, 0, 0xFFFFFF);
    $size_img = getimagesize($filename);
    $src_ratio=$size_img[0]/$size_img[1];
    if ($src_ratio>$ratio) {
        $old_w=$size_img[0];
        $size_img[0]=floor($size_img[1]*$ratio);
        $old_w=floor($old_w*$w/$size_img[0]);
    }
    else {
        $old_h=$size_img[1];
        $size_img[1]=floor($size_img[0]/$ratio);
        $old_h=floor($old_h*$h/$size_img[1]);
    }
    switch ($size_img['mime']) {
      case 'image/jpeg':
                $src_img = imagecreatefromjpeg($filename);
            break;
            case 'image/gif':
                $src_img = imagecreatefromgif($filename);
            break;
      case 'image/png':
                $src_img = imagecreatefrompng($filename);
            break;
    }
    imagecopyresampled($dest_img, $src_img, 0, 0, 0, 0, $w, $h, $size_img[0], $size_img[1]);

    // тут определим новое имя файла (и/или путь) для сохранения
    $file_info=pathinfo($filename);
    $filename_new = str_replace('.'.$file_info['extension'], '_mini.'.$file_info['extension'], $filename);

    switch ($size_img['mime']) {
        case 'image/jpeg':
            imagejpeg($dest_img,$filename_new);
        break;
        case 'image/gif':
            imagegif($dest_img,$filename_new);
        break;
        case 'image/png':
            imagepng($dest_img,$filename_new);
        break;
    }

    imagedestroy($dest_img);
    imagedestroy($src_img);
}
```

Comment: Stanislav@ да вот у меня есть своя тоже функция такая но я не пойму как мне надо указать эту картинку в нее - просто вставить путьт ее типа так: ./folder1/1782378882222311.jpg ???

Comment: Путь к картинке нужен полный. При загрузке файла, путь хранится в $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'] , если вы сделали move_uploaded_file(), то, соответственно, другой путь.